# Multiple app-id in Chrome command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I have a launcher that loads Chrome in a wrapper but only with one extension, I would like to have it load two (or perhaps more!) as well.. I can't figure out the syntax and my google-fu has failed me.

This is the original command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ckoejdikoiejoakefebpdfokijadifom
```

How do I also have it load this app-id as well?

```
ljmjmhjkcgfmfdhgplikncgndbdeckci
```

I tried semicolon, colon, space, adding another --app-id= into it.. nothing..  this must be possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would like to have it load two or more apps.

You need to use a comma `,` to separate the list of apps.

Try the following command line (quoted to prevent scrollbar):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ckoejdikoiejoakefebpdfokijadifom,ljmjmhjkcgfmfdhgplikncgndbdeckci

Note:

- If you want to load extensions you need to use a different option `--load-extension`.

---

#### List of Chromium Command Line Switches

> - `--load-apps` - Path to a **comma-separated** list of apps to load at startup.
>
>   The first app in the list will be launched.
> - `--load-extension` - Loads an extension from the specified directory

Source [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

---

#### switches.cc

```
// Path to a comma-separated list of apps to load at startup.  
// The first app in the list will be launched.
const char kLoadApps[] = "load-apps";
```

...

```
// Loads an extension from the specified directory.
const char kLoadExtension[] = "load-extension";
```

Source [switches.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/common/switches.cc&q=kLoadApps&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

Comment: Ok I don't mind having a secondary file that lists the apps, but can you expand a bit?  I have this command line in a shortcut on my desktop so I have room for exactly one line.  What would the full line look like?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Interesting, so a comma is the first thing I tried, and now it just loads a blank tab.  A bit more background, this launcher simply launches the Google Play Music app, I just want to also have it load the midnight theme extension as well.  With just the first app, it works perfect.  But when adding the comma, it just loads a blank tab

Comment: Try adding a different flag `--load-extension` (Loads an extension from the specified directory) to load the midnight theme extension. I guess the the midnight theme extension is **not an app**.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain!  So with load extension I need to use the file path to the extension?  Which is deep within my user files, so it looks like --load-extension=\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ljmjmhjkcgfmfdhgplikncgndbdeckci\2.3.5_0  (note, tried this, doesn't work)

Comment: Put the directory in quotes `--load-extension="\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ljmjmhjkcgfmfdhgplikncgndbdeckci\2.3.5_0"

Comment: See [Load unpacked Chrome extension programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32641579)